# VS Code How to UNDO Replace All

Tags: visual-studio-code, replace

VS Code on Windows
changes were done with find and replace in the whole folder and with that, all of them saved automatically. 
doing find and replace again would create a mess in different places.
undo did nothing. 
ctrl+z did nothing. 
How to **UNDO find and replace** through the **whole folder?**
Thanks!

[this is the picture where you can see how I messed up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGtBf.png)

Comment: use version control before you do such operation, or temporary make a zip of the folder

Comment: removing mysql tag, this doesn't seem to be relevant

Comment: if you hold ```ctrl``` and click ```z``` multiple times even when all changes are reverted in the file, visual studio will ask if you want to revert all changes in other files as well. click yes. happened to me, when I just wanted to redo in the current file, but it did for all find replaces.

Answer (score 18):

Open up one of the affected files, and Ctrl-Z (Undo) in it. It will cascade and undo all the other files as well.

Comment: Verified this worked within a single vscode workspace containing mulitple repositories and 530 changes across 20+ files. (Just one `Ctrl+Z` was sufficient for vscode to open all files that were changed and to change them back.  All I had to do was save the changes (and hence the files, back into their original form).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it looks like this isn’t possible. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/47783) for this from 2018, but no progress on it that I see.

If you’re using a VC system, I would recommend you try and see if there’s anyway to recover from it.

Comment: Thanks. I am tending more into thinking about a new extension. Lets work on my skills then :D

Comment: Thank you for the response! Here is an example https://imfeld.dev/writing/starting_with_solana_part02